# Converting full names to 'Surname, First name' format on Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that record some author names like this:

```
A  
A. Dagliati
A. Zambelli
A.H.M. ter Hofstede
Agnes Bates Koschmider
Ágnes Vathy-Fogarassy
Ahmed B. Najjar
Ala Norani
```

I want column B to receive some formula such that B will display the last name, a comma, and the first/middle name, like this:

```
A                         B
A. Dagliati               Dagliati, A.               
A. Zambelli               Zambelli, A.
A.H.M. ter Hofstede       Hofstede, A.H.M. ter
Agnes Bates Koschmider    Koschmider, Agnes Bates
Ágnes Vathy-Fogarassy     Vathy-Fogarassy, Ágnes
Ahmed B. Najjar           Najjar, Ahmed B.
Ala Norani                Norani, Ala
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't do it with a simple rule because prefixes like van and ter are really part of the surname. Sometimes 'double-barrelled' surnames are separated by a space rather than hyphen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula on row 2 of your sheet, with an empty column below it.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,".+\s(.+)") &", " & LEFT(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,".+\s(.+)") )),""))
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=CONCAT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))),1)), CONCAT(", ", LEFT(A1, FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))),1))))
```

Basically, we are cutting off text from last index of " " (whitespace), append comma and do same from beginning.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to use regular expression replacement. It's not pretty, but it's the easiest way to search for the delimiter and perform the replacement using capture groups. I am still working on how to properly support cases where there is a single name like "A". For now it assumes it is the surname. Here is the formula:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.*?)([^ ]+)$", "$2, $1")
```

This function will search for any character non-greedily (`.*?` see [the docs for RE2 here](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt#L28)) which will allow the second capture group to find all the characters from the end of the string to the first delimiter which is a space in this case. Since we are using capture groups in the regular expression we can reference them in the replacement string using the `$1` and `$2` placeholders.

The output is as desired:

[image: screenshot of an example spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of:

- [SPLIT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [COLUMNS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093374)
- [INDEX()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [ARRAY_CONSTRAIN()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036)
- [JOIN()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)

```
=JOIN(
  ", ",
  INDEX(SPLIT(A2, " "), 1, COLUMNS(SPLIT(A2, " "))),
  JOIN(" ", ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(A2, " "), 1, COLUMNS(SPLIT(A2, " "))-1))
)
```

#### Get the last name

1. Split up the name by space `SPLIT(A2, " ")`
2. Get the number of names `COLUMNS(SPLIT(A2, " "))`
3. Select on the last name `INDEX(SPLIT(A2, " "), 1, COLUMNS(SPLIT(A2, " ")))`

#### Get the other names

1. Split up the name by space again `SPLIT(A2, " ")`
2. Get all names except the last name `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(A2, " "), 1, COLUMNS(SPLIT(A2, " "))-1)`
3. Join them back together `JOIN(" ", ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(A2, " "), 1, COLUMNS(SPLIT(A2, " "))-1))`

#### Join in desired order

1. `JOIN(", ", LAST_NAME_FORMULA, OTHER_NAMES_FORMULA)`